# What is the OCNH2 group called?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

what is the product of reaction of Traut's reagent with aliphatic hydroxyl called? I am reacting Traut's reagent with Fmoc protected Doxorubicin and I just need to know the name of the product after Traut's regent reacts with the hydroxyl group. What is $\ce{OCNH2}$ called? I am looking for a name for $\ce{OCNH2}$ circled in red.

[image: Sulfhydryl N-Fmoc Dox]

Answer (score 6):

The group itself unprotonated is called a carboximidate as noted by the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboximidate) page.  The acid that the group is derived from is carboximidic acid.  As is common practice with imines, the nomenclature for the corresponding protonated halide is done by removing -es, adding -ium, and the halide name.  If this is done using the acid name, the group will be called a carboximinium chloride.

Comment: Maybe carboximiDium chloride?

Answer (score 5):

There is a paper ([1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0277538700837742)) on imino-ether salts with rather similar structure including $\ce{-C(NH2+)O\! -}$ group:

[image]

This compound comes with two defined names, which OP can use as an example:

1. Hydrogenethylpropylimidate tetrachloroaurate(III) (paper)
2. 1-(Ethoxy)propylimidium tetrachloro-gold(III) (generated by CCDC)

Subjectively, carboximidate fits perfectly if the group wouldn't carry a positive charge; as long as this is the case, probably *carboximidium* would fit better.

(1) Potts, R. A.; Gaj, D. L.; Schneider, W. F.; Dean, N. S.; Kampf, J. W.; Oliver, J. P. Polyhedron 1991, 10 (14), 1631–1637. [DOI: 10.1016/S0277-5387(00)83774-2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0277538700837742)